# Vuejs - Show/Hide block when checkbox checked, when checkbox is component

Tags: vue.js

i need to show or hide block when checkbox is checked or unchecked. Checkbox is component, what including in layout. Option what must show or hide located in layout. For example:

Layout page:

```
<template lang="pug">

  div
    checkbox(caption="test")
    div(v-if="showExtend")
      p lorem ipsum

</template>

<script>
  data() {
    return: {
      showExtend: false
    }
  }
</script>
```

Checkbox component:

```
<template lang="pug">
  label
     input(type="checkbox", :name="name", :checked="checked")
     span(v-html="caption")

</template>

<script>
  props: {
        caption: {
            type: String
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        checked: {
            type: Boolean
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `@change` event in checkbox component input element, in your example you have 1-way binding. See: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/custom-checkbox-component/1120/5, custom v-model: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Checkbox component:

```vue
<template lang="pug">
  label
     input(type="checkbox", :name="name", :checked="value", @change="$emit('input', $event.target.checked)")
     span(v-html="caption")
</template>
<script>
  props: ["caption", "name", "value"]
</script>
```

Layout:

```vue
<template lang="pug">
  div
    checkbox(caption="test", v-model="showExtend")
    div(v-if="showExtend")
      p lorem ipsum

</template>

<script>
  data() {
    return: {
      showExtend: false
    }
  }
</script>
```

You can test it:

```js
new Vue({el:'#layout', data:{showExtend:false}})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>
<template id="checkbox">
  <label>
     <input type="checkbox" :name="name" :checked="value" @change="$emit('input', $event.target.checked)">
     <span v-html="caption"></span>
  </label>
</template>
<script>
  Vue.component('checkbox', {template:'#checkbox', props: ["caption", "name", "value"]})
</script>
<div id="layout">
  <checkbox caption="test" v-model="showExtend"></checkbox>
  <div v-if="showExtend">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When i check, and uncheck checkbox, showExtend dont return to false

Comment: checkbox value says always on

Comment: Fixed. It must be: `@change="$emit('input', $event.target.checked)"`