# Adding a Navigation Guard for a Vue.js view

Tags: vue.js, frontend

I'm trying to add a "terms of use" checkbox to a Vue.js view. I tried to use veevalidate but it generates errors because of the dependencies while building. So, I decided not to use it and I would like to make it without using any library like that.

Here is the current content of the view file:

```html
<template>
    <div class="main-view">
        <LobbyScreen v-if="isInLobby" />
        <template v-else>
            <TopBar :is-in-call="showChatInSidebar" />
            <transition name="fade">
                <ChatView v-if="!showChatInSidebar" />
                <template v-else>
                    <CallView :token="token" />
                </template>
            </transition>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CallView from '../components/CallView/CallView'
import ChatView from '../components/ChatView'
import LobbyScreen from '../components/LobbyScreen'
import TopBar from '../components/TopBar/TopBar'
import isInLobby from '../mixins/isInLobby'
import isInCall from '../mixins/isInCall'
import participant from '../mixins/participant'

export default {
    name: 'MainView',
    components: {
        ChatView,
        LobbyScreen,
        TopBar,
        CallView,
    },

    mixins: [
        isInLobby,
        isInCall,
        participant,
    ],

    props: {
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    },

    computed: {
        conversation() {
            return this.$store.getters.conversation(this.token)
        },

        showChatInSidebar() {
            return this.isInCall
        },
    },

    watch: {
        isInLobby(isInLobby) {
            // User is now blocked by the lobby
            if (isInLobby && this.isInCall) {
                this.$store.dispatch('leaveCall', {
                    token: this.token,
                    participantIdentifier: this.$store.getters.getParticipantIdentifier(),
                })
            }
        },
    },

}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

.main-view {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: space-between;
}
</style>
```

I found an answer to a question that is similar to mine,
How can I implement this solution to my view? :
[Vuejs - Show/Hide block when checkbox checked, when checkbox is component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730043/vuejs-show-hide-block-when-checkbox-checked-when-checkbox-is-component)

EDIT:
I tried an alternative solution using navigation guard in router.js but it doesn't show the confirmation box when I try to go to a link with "call" path. Here is the code in router.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import { getRootUrl, generateUrl } from '@nextcloud/router'
import MainView from '../views/MainView.vue'
import NotFoundView from '../views/NotFoundView.vue'
import SessionConflictView from '../views/SessionConflictView.vue'
import WelcomeView from '../views/WelcomeView.vue'
import VuejsDialog from 'vuejs-dialog'
import 'vuejs-dialog/dist/vuejs-dialog.min.css'

Vue.use(VuejsDialog)
Vue.use(Router)

const webRootWithIndexPHP = getRootUrl() + '/index.php'
const doesURLContainIndexPHP = window.location.pathname.startsWith(webRootWithIndexPHP)
const base = generateUrl('/', {}, {
    noRewrite: doesURLContainIndexPHP,
})

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    // if index.php is in the url AND we got this far, then it's working:
    // let's keep using index.php in the url
    base,
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/apps/spreed',
            name: 'root',
            component: WelcomeView,
            props: true,
        },
        {
            path: '/apps/spreed/not-found',
            name: 'notfound',
            component: NotFoundView,
            props: true,
        },
        {
            path: '/apps/spreed/duplicate-session',
            name: 'duplicatesession',
            component: SessionConflictView,
            props: true,
        },
        {
            path: '/call/:token',
            beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
                this.$dialog.confirm('Do you accept the terms of use and privacy policy?')
                    .then(function() {
                        next()
                    })
                    .catch(function() {
                        next(false)
                    })
            },
            name: 'conversation',
            component: MainView,
            props: true,
        },
    ],
})
```

Any solution to one of these alternatives would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, but if you'd like a button which is disabled/not disabled based on if a box is ticked:

1. Put a checkbox in your HTML
2. Put a button in your HTML
3. Give the checkbox a v-model e.g. v-model="checked"
4. Give the button a conditional disabled attribute e.g. :disabled="buttonIsDisabled"
5. Put 2 new properties in your vue class e.g.
   buttonIsDisabled: boolean = true;      checked: boolean = false;
6. Watch the checked value. When it is changed, it will change the button property e.g.:

   @Watch("checked")
   onChanged(newValue: any, oldValue: any) {
   if (this.checked === true) {
   this.checked = newValue
   return this.buttonIsDisabled = false
   }
   if (this.checked === false) {
   this.checked = newValue
   return this.buttonIsDisabled = true
   }
   }

This example uses the way the code is formatted in my project it may be formatted differently in yours, but the same method should apply if you're trying to do what i think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I simply want to allow the user to access MainView only if he accepts the terms of use. So, I want a confirmation dialog that appears when a user tries to access MainView and allow to navigate it if the confirmation dialog returns true.

Comment: This is where I try to use Vue's Navigation Guard, but it doesn't work:

routes: [
        {
            path: '/call/:token',
            beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
                this.$dialog.confirm('Do you accept the terms of use?')
                    .then(function() {
                        next()
                    })
                    .catch(function() {
                        next(false)
                    })
            },
            name: 'conversation',
            component: MainView,
            props: true,
        },
    ],

Comment: I've not used Vue Navguard before, however you might find form validation useful:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html?redirect=true

Comment: It is a useful link for form validations, thanks for sharing it. Even though I asked for a checkbox validation in the title of my question, I think it would be better to prevent users that come from a direct link, from navigating to a view. So whenever a visitor wants to visit a URL that contains "call" path, a modal dialog must appear and prevent the user until he clicks accept button on the dialog. That's why I try to use Navigation Guards

Comment: Sorry, it's not something I've set up before, the best I can do is redirect you here:
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2019/07/getting-started-vuejs-navigation-guards-restrict-access-routes/
Good luck!